# what the mean of "go through","go through divorce" and the following sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning

what the mean of "go through","go through divorce" and the following sentence?

i watched my parents **go through** a long,painful and messy **divorce**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting a divorce is not simple. It's a long, difficult process, and in English, you "go through" the process, like going through a tunnel.

Comment: thanks a lot,and would you please explain to me the precise meaning of sentence.

Comment: A translation would be: "I watched the whole process of my parents getting divorced, which took a long time, was emotionally painful for them, and was a messy process."